# Android : Get day of the week from date?

Tags: java, android, datetime, date-format

How can i format the date to be like this

> Mon, 27 Nov 2011

```
    public static String sFleTimeToDate(double ft) {
           double date = ft / 10000 - 11644455600000L;
           date += TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset((long) date);
           return DateFormat.format("ddd, dd MMM yyyy", new Date((long) date)).toString();
}
```

but this function return

> 027, 27 Nov 2011

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change your DateFormat.format to

```
 DateFormat.format("EEE, dd MMM yyyy", new Date((long) date)).toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

For getting day in week you have to use `EEE`

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy);
```

You can create any format as you desire just have a look at [`this`](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/) Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

look at this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm). It shows various format options.

I have updated your method, try it now,

```
public static String sFleTimeToDate(double ft) {
       double date = ft / 10000 - 11644455600000L;
       date += TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset((long) date);
       return DateFormat.format("E, dd MMM yyyy", new Date((long) date)).toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To Get Current Date With your expected Format:

```
String currentDateTimeString =DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date()); 
      txtToday.setText(currentDateTimeString);
```